# Chrome - SVG cutting off text with <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, svg

I currently have an issue where an `<svg>` element is placed within a `<div>`. I know this is due to the text being rendered from the bottom left corner, but I didn't want to use SVG's 'Dominant Baseline' attribute as it's not supported in IE as far as I'm aware.

[image: Chrome cutting off text in SVG]

Interestingly, the above works fine in IE, just not in Chrome. Any idea why this could be or how I could solve it?

Please see a basic example of this below (works in IE, not chrome):

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id='test'>
    <svg id='svgName'>
        <text font-size='200'>
            testing
        </text>
    </svg>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#test {
    height: 300px;
}

#svgName {
    margin-top: 150px;
}
```

Comment: For the time being I've just set a `text-anchor` within the SVG. But this still feels and looks like a bug within Chrome.

Comment: Can you add your HTML and CSS so that it's possible to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Please include a [MCVE].

Comment: Example code added - replicates the issue in chrome.